# preg_match for a number or a specific word

Tags: regex, preg-match

I really suck at regexp, I'm trying to figure out how to check if string is either a number or a specific word, for example **blah**

```
//regex for number or a specific word "blah"
1 //ok
1a //not ok
5448 //ok
blah // ok
my horse is on fire // not ok
lalala //not ok
```

Comment: i said a specific word, not any word

Comment: Create a list of your _specific words_ and check if the input is one of those?

Comment: @devnull did I mentioned i need a regexp?

Comment: So it won't be much different from what was suggested earlier, right?  `[0-9]+|blah`  You might want to add anchors to denote start & end of match.

Comment: @Benedictus The tag kind of implies this...

Comment: Yes, the tag implies that.  And you started `I really suck at regex` -- that substantiates it.

Comment: @devnull [0-9]+|blah was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @Benedictus Did you know that `[0-9]+|blah` __is a regex__.

Comment: @devnull didn't i just said that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(blah|\d+)$
```

Working example at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/pT4sF1)